# Notepad++ Expression to change text according to need

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text file and i am using Notepad++
and The text looks like this:

```
42105-100 - 42110-131
42200-100 - 42221-131
42400-100 - 42400-131
42550-100 - 42550-131
55000-100 - 55000-131
```

now I need an regular expression to convert this text into

```
OR ( FromAccount = 42105 AND FromBranch= 100  AND ToAccount = 42110 AND ToBranch = 131)
OR ( FromAccount = 42200 AND FromBranch= 100  AND ToAccount = 42221 AND ToBranch = 131)
OR ( FromAccount = 42400 AND FromBranch= 100  AND ToAccount = 42400 AND ToBranch = 131)
OR ( FromAccount = 42550 AND FromBranch= 100  AND ToAccount = 42550 AND ToBranch = 131)
OR ( FromAccount = 55000 AND FromBranch= 100  AND ToAccount = 55000 AND ToBranch = 131)
```

I know this is possible by creating regular expression and just click "Replace all" button. but the problem is i am unable to create this expression.

please help me to create this expression

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(\d{5})-(\d{3}) - (\d{5})-(\d{3})$
```

and replace with `OR \( FromAccount = $1 AND FromBranch= $2  AND ToAccount = $3 AND ToBranch = $4\)`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d{5})` - Group 1 (`$1`): 5 digits
- `-`  - hyphen
- `(\d{3})`  - Group 2 (`$2`): 3 digits
- `-`  - a hyphen within spaces
- `(\d{5})` - Group 3 (`$3`): 5 digits
- `-`  - hyphen
- `(\d{3})` - Group 4 (`$4`): 3 digits
- `$` - end of line

In the replacement, `(` and `)` must be escaped.

[image]